# What is the "include" folder used for in a Katalon Studio project

Tags: cucumber, bdd, katalon-studio

Similarly to what is being asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51132624/folders-meaning-in-katalon-project), which is yet without answer, I'm struggling to understand how should I properly use folders in a Katalon Studio project.

In particular, so far I wasn't able to trigger creation of any file in the `Include` subfolders.

Which files should I expect to find there? Depending on the answer, I can decide wether to put them under version control or go and default .gitignore to exclude `Include`.

I watched the available tutorials, but so far I couldn't grasp it (unless I missed something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty un-intuitevly named, but `Include` folder is used for [BDD integration](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/cucumber-features-file.html#add-feature-files).

Include folder should include two subfolders: one for feature files and the other for step definition files.

Comment: so /feature is BDD description, /scripts is BDD step definition and /config?

Comment: Katalon uses Cucumber implementation of BDD. Feature files describe the feature in the business readable language, and step definition files are basically code for execution of the business readable steps. The two are usually mapped one to the other via regex (this is what Cucumber basically does).

Comment: So, don't put homebrewed library files in there to include in your Keywords, gotcha